# Linux and S3 sleep on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon gen 11

Tags: linux, sleep, thinkpad

I got a new laptop, a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon gen 11, and it doesn't support S3 sleep mode. When in sleep the battery continues to drain, badly.

```
~ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle]
```

```
journactl |grep ACPI
ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S4 S5)
```

I've upgraded the Bios to latest version `N3XET45W (1.20)`, and these are the only option available

[image]

I read of several posts suggesting to search an option in BIOS to enable Linux suspend.
Why Lenovo removed S3 sleep mode? What I should try?

Comment: Do the BIOS `>` buttons allow to see more options ?

Comment: the help describing that setting :)

Comment: I have Lenovo X1 and X13 machines here. From my research, it appears Lenovo has not resolved all the issues and is not using it right now. Just use ordinary Suspend. That works very well.

Comment: When in sleep the battery continues to drain, badly.   .........   That would be the Linux power driver. No issues here with Lenovo X machines suspending and no (very little) battery drain whilst suspended.